# Replacing a string with another in the database result using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a database table containing some Permanent Texts which I will be outputting to my user interactions. The problem is that I need to change some parts of these Permanent Text answers when querying the Database.

For example this is one of the responses I will be giving to the user:

```
I'm sorry, your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "ANSWER". Don't demoralize yourself and keep training!
```

But as you see the `ANSWER` should be the number or text I would like to replace during the query so I get the correct result, as an example result:

```
I'm sorry, your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "Option 1". Don't demoralize yourself and keep training!
```

I am doing these queries inside CodeIgniter (PHP Framework) and this is the style of code I'm using:

```
public function mo_response_content($mo_response_content_id)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $mo_response_content_id);

    // Code to add for replacing part of the result


    $query = $this->db->get('actions_mo_contents');
    $row = $query->row();
    if ($row)
    {
        return $row;
    } else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

How can I replace the `ANSWER` string during the database query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MySQL [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function as the following:

```
$this->db->select("*, REPLACE(string_column, 'ANSWER', 'replaceTextHere') AS 'response'");
```

Comment: Mamnoon, would you happen to know how to format this into a codeigniter friendly way (similar to the function above)?

Comment: @Freelancing_Best_Choice Actually there's no full support of SQL functions in CI Active record. This way is okay. However, you can query the database manually by using `query();` method.

Comment: I was hoping it existed, since I would rather not change the current format inside my models, but anyway it's working fine. 

باز هم ممنون

Comment: awesome concept dear made my day have been thinking for that how i am gona fix this i ci and you did it love u